# JQuery.Ajax makes unwanted multiple requests

Tags: jquery, ajax, onsubmit

I have a pretty basic form with a textbox and a submit button. The form is supposed to accept an email and send it to a PHP page for processing, via an ajax request. The form is not actually submitted though. Instead, an onSubmit event is used to call a function, where the Ajax request is made if the email is of valid format. However, I see that multiple requests are being made to the PHP page (through the logs), but am puzzled as to why. Here are some potential causes that I have checked/tried:

- post_email() function called multiple times - Not calling anywhere else, other than in the onSubmit event
- user clicking multiple times - may be possible, but some Ajax calls are within 10ths of a second from each other. I'm confirming this because in the PHP page, I'm logging every request
- Multiple versions of jQuery are being loaded within the site (legacy code). My thought was that the .ajax call was being made for each version loaded. However, I added the jQuery.fn.jquery data string to every ajax call and only one version is used on this page

Here is the code I'm using:

HTML CODE

```
<form id="post_em" name="post_em" method="post" onSubmit="return post_email()">
    <h3>enter e-mail:</h3>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    <div id="em_response"></div>
</form>
```

JS CODE

```
function post_email() {
    if(isValidEmailAddress(jQuery("#email").val()))
    {
        var optincurlurl = "opt_in.php";
        var dataString = jQuery("#post_em").serialize();

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: optincurlurl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: dataString+"&jQuery="+jQuery.fn.jquery,
            datatype: "text",
            timeout: 3600,
            error: function(){
                jQuery("#em_response").html("Error.");
                jQuery("#em_response").show();
            },
            success: function(data){
                jQuery("#em_response").html(data);
                jQuery("#em_response").show();
            }
        });

    } else
        alert("invalid email.");

    return false;
}
```

Please let me know if you spot any potential reasons as to why the Ajax call is being made multiple times.

thanks.

Comment: I don't see any reason for it to be posting more than once without user clicking more than once.

Comment: I have just tried creating the same (just i have used $('#post_em').submit instead of onSubmit) and got what you wanted... Maybe you have more ajax calls in the php script you are calling (opt_in.php) ?